# netlink socket address structure (nl_group)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

The netlink socket address structure is shown in the following,

```
struct sockaddr_nl
{
    sa_family_t nl_family;  /* AF_NETLINK   */
    unsigned short  nl_pad;     /* zero     */
    __u32       nl_pid;     /* process pid  */
    __u32       nl_groups;  /* multicast groups mask */
};
```

Two questions here:

1. About the process id, does zero mean to root privilege and this means to process id?
2. what does nl_groups mean? Does this mean I can configure this to do unicast?

Thanks

Comment: Read this page http://linux.die.net/man/7/netlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `nl_pid` is Port ID (see [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/netlink.h?v=3.13#L35)) and it has nothing to do with privileges.
2. `nl_groups` as commentary tolds is multicast groubps mask. Netlink messages can be sent unitcast(to given PID - port ID), multicast and broadcast withing given netlink family (e.g. netfilter, generic, etc.)